# Linking button to launch activity

Tags: android

Im trying to link up the array[1] to launch an activity but its showing me an error on this line 
 Intent i1 = new Intent(this, Difficulty.class); If any one sees where im going wrong help me please

 
the error reads "The constructor Intent(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}, Class) is undefined"

```
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            if ("Green".equals(items[1]))
            {Intent intent = new Intent();
            Intent i1 = new Intent(this, Diff.class);
            startActivity(i1);;}

        }
        }).show();
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Comment: Hi,u got your solution or not???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Intent i1 = new Intent(this, Diff.class);
```

to

```
Intent i1 = new Intent(TheNameOfYourActivity.this, diff.class);
```

and replace "TheNameOfYourActivity" with the name of the activity that this is taking place inside of.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are starting the intent in the dialog onclick listener, ***this*** will refer to the dialog instance instead of your activity class (which i am assuming you are calling the code from).

To fix this problem, you need to create a variable which holds a reference to your activity, and use that instead of *this*.